# IE7/8 not parsing through newly created jQuery object

Tags: jquery, string, internet-explorer

Ok, so, let's say I have a string:

```
var xmlString = '<main><id>5</id><name>test-string</name></main>';
```

I then want this string to behave like it's a jQuery obj:

```
var xmlString = '<main><id>5</id><name>test-string</name></main>',
    xmlString = $(xmlString);
```

Once I do that, I would like to find the value of the ID node:

```
var xmlString = '<main><id>5</id><name>test-string</name></main>',
    xmlString = $(xmlString),
    findIdTest = xmlString.find('id').text(),
    filterIdTest = xmlString.filter('main').find('id').text();
```

I try two methods,

`xmlString.find('id').text()`

and

```
filterIdTest = xmlString.filter('main').find('id').text();
```

In FF, Chrome, and IE9, the result is always **5**, for both methods.

In IE7 and IE8, I get nothing.. an (empty string)..

Does anyone know why this happening..?

Here's a fiddle to work with and troubleshoot:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmeVY/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jQuery.parseXML` before you create the jQuery object to create a valid XML document.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

```
var xmlString = '<main><id>5</id><name>test-string</name></main>',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString),
    myObj = $(xmlDoc);

myObj.find("id").text();
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I understand the reasoning behind it, but is there any documented info that you know of as to why IE7 and IE8 need to know that the string should be treated like XML and IE9 could care less? Just out of curiosity at this point.

Comment: Worth a read: http://thingsinjars.com/post/371/investigating-ies-innerhtml/ Looks like `innerHTML` (which jQuery uses internally) in IE does not like non-standard HTML elements. By using `parseXML` first, you are passing a Document Fragment into jQuery, which bypasses using `innerHTML` to update the DOM.

Comment: Awesome stuff Gary! Thanks, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the $.parseXML() function.

try this:

```
var xmlString = $.parseXML('<main><id>5</id><name>test-string</name></main>');
$xmlString = $(xmlString);
alert($xmlString.find('id').text());
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ for more info and examples.

Hope that helps!
-Ted

Aw crap saw someone beat me to it.